# Получить список записей с одинаковыми параметрами

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица организаций у которой есть поле user_id т.е. какому юзеру она принадлежит.
Я хочу получить список организаций которые относятся к одну му тому же юзеру т.е. если у юзера больше чем одна организация то она должнв попасть в список.
Если я пробую сделать каунт user_id то надо соответвенно сделать группировку но в таком случае показывает только одну организацию с количеством скажем так дублирующихся айдишников. Подскажите как правильно получить такой список.

```
id user_id name
1    100      test
2    101      test_2
3    100      test_3
4    102      test_4
5    102      test_5
```

По результатам выборки я должен получить 1,3,4,5 айдишники

Comment: `если у юзера больше чем одна организация то она должнв попасть в список` а при чем тут дубликаты?

Comment: лучше пример данных приведите и желаемый результат из них

Comment: *Подскажите как правильно получить такой список.* Сначала надо просто хорошо подумать, по какому именно параметру следует группировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
select user_id, id
from organization o
where exists (
   select 1
   from organization dup
   where dup.user_id = o.user_id AND dup.id != o.id
)
```

Или так:

```
select user_id, id
from organization
where user_id in  (
   select user_id
   from organization 
   group by user_id
   having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: лучше второе на джойн с подзапросом переделать